# Input Method & Engine for Japanese & Chinese

Tags: fonts, ibus, japanese, chinese, fcitx

Does anyone have experience with input methods and engines such as ibus, fcitx, uim, anthy, mozc?

Which one would you guys recommend for Japanese/ For Chinese?

And do they work inside a terminal? inside Vim/Emacs? And most importantly, do they require a Desktop Environment by any chance? (I'm currently using a tiling wm.)

Also, what's everyone's favorite Japanese/Chinese Font?

Answer (score 2):

The default IM framework on Ubuntu for typing Chinese or Japanese is Fcitx. Please see [this spot](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html#complex) in the official documentation.

I think that IBus and Fcitx are the ones which are best supported. Won't say anything more about a recommendation; in the end it's about personal preferences.

AFAIK they work fine in terminals. Setting it up without a desktop environment is of course a bit different compared to the linked example in the official desktop guide.

Default fonts in Ubuntu are:

- for Chinese: Noto Sans (the `fonts-noto-cjk` package)
- for Japanese: Takao (the `fonts-takao-*` packages)